# codeigniter saving posts twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a Codeingiter application that stores posts into a database using jquery! but the problem is that it stores same data twice! I reviewed the code but I can't seem to figure it out! please help me!
View:

```
<div id="poster">
    <label id="poster_label" > State your feeling.. </label> <br />
    <textarea rows="3" cols="60" id="poster_textarea" ></textarea> <br />
    <input type="button" id="poster_button" value="Publish" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#poster_button').click(function(){
    if(!$('#poster_textarea').val()){
        $('#poster_textarea').css('border','1px solid pink').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        var poster_textarea = $('#poster_textarea').val();
        var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/blog/add_post";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: 'poster_textarea='+poster_textarea,
            //datatype: "json",
            success: function() 
            {
                alert('saved');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
function add_post(){
    $post_data = array(
        'id'            => '',
        'user_id'   =>  '11330',
        'content'   =>  $this->input->post('poster_textarea'),
        'date_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'status'        =>  '1'
    );
    $this->blog_model->add_post($post_data);
}
```

Model:

```
function add_post($post_data){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

Comment: if you have firebug then you need to click the NET TAB and submit the form to check that how many posts do it send.

Comment: @Syed Haider Hassan: well of course it sends two posts.. and it shows in firebug! but why is should post two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This in your JS.
It creates the DOM Tree as far as i think..

```
$('#poster_button').click(function(e){
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
if(!$('#poster_textarea').val()){
        $('#poster_textarea').css('border','1px solid pink').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        var poster_textarea = $('#poster_textarea').val();
        var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/blog/add_post";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: 'poster_textarea='+poster_textarea,
            //datatype: "json",
            success: function() 
            {
                alert('saved');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked fine, But what does the function stopImmediatePropagation() do?

Comment: it keep continue making DOM Tree, Until you Refresh Page.
So in order to stop it you need to use the function..
I use it alot in my projects when i use ajax :p

Also check this Page.
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: Thank you so much friend for the great info!